# How to prevent soapConnection.call from stripping CDATA - Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, soap, soapui, unmarshalling, cdata

I am calling a SOAP web service using the following code (from spring boot application). The web service will return a response with XML (within CDATA) in one of the elements (Result). My requirement is to unmarshall the soap response and convert it into java object. I don't have access to modify the soap service. Based on the soap request, Result element will have String value or an XML (within CDATA). My unmarshalling program works perfectly when the Result element has string value but it fails if the Result element has XML without CDATA.

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(<SOAPMessage request>, <soapEndpointUrl>);
```

When I print the response, CDATA was missing whereas when I test the same using SOAP UI, I am getting a response with CDATA in it.

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapResponse.writeTo(out);
        System.out.println("Output..............:"+out.toString());
```

**Output from application**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://www.someurl/su">
            <Result>&lt;?xml version="1.0"
                encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;MyName&gt;&lt;System
                System="ABC" ValidLogin="False" Reason="User ID not found in
                system." /&gt;&lt;/MyName&gt;</Result>
        </Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**SOAP response from SOAPUI Tool**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <Response xmlns="http://www.someurl/su">
         <Result><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><MyName><System System="ABC" ValidLogin="False" Reason="User ID not found in system."/></MyName>]]></Result>
      </Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Code to Unmarshall the data**

```
String soapBodyStr = "";
SOAPBody soapBody = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();
Document doc = soapBody.extractContentAsDocument();
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "script");
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
writer.flush();
soapBodyStr = writer.toString();
soapBodyStr = soapBodyStr.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
soapBodyStr = soapBodyStr.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
soapConnection.close();
```

**Contents of soapBodyStr (Without SOAP envelop)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <Response xmlns="http://www.someurl/su">
            <Result><?xml version="1.0"
                encoding="utf-8"?><MyName><System
                System="ABC" ValidLogin="False" Reason="User ID not found in
                system." /></MyName></Result>
        </Response>


StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(soapBodyStr);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Response response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);  //getting error here
String soapResponse = Response.getResult();
```

**Exception**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 27; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.]
```

unmarshal is working if i manually add CDATA to the SOAP response. is there way by which we can get the soap response with CDATA. Your help is highly appreciated.